# Importing a csv with Roo of 55 rows is causing an ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, cookies, import, roo

I'm using [roo-rb/roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) to import csv files of data into my database.  But with 55 rows, 4 columns, I am getting an ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow error.  Anyone know what could be causing this or what would be trying to create this cookie that I guess is maxing out?

Here is my import function:

```
  def self.import(file)
    result = {
        errors: 0,
        success: 0,
        row_results: { }
    }

    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)

    transaction do
      (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]

        file_row_hash = row.to_hash
        first_name = file_row_hash['first_name']
        last_name = file_row_hash['last_name']
        company_name = file_row_hash['company_name']
        email = file_row_hash['email']
        company = Company.new(:name => company_name)

        if company.save
          password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
          user = StaffMember.new({ :email => email, :encrypted_password => password, :first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name, :company_id => company.id })

          if user.save
            result[:success] += 1
            result[:row_results][i] = "row #{i}: #{company['name']} and #{company['first_name']} + #{company['last_name']} was successfully created"
          else
            result[:errors] += 1
            result[:row_results][i] = "row #{i}: #{company['name']} saved BUT staff_member #{company['first_name']} + #{company['last_name']} failed to save"
          end
        else
          result[:errors] += 1
          result[:row_results][i] = "row #{i}: #{company['name']} and #{company['first_name']} + #{company['last_name']} failed to be created."
        end
      end
    end
    return result
  end
```

Comment: Hey I am stuck on the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by changing the way your cookie is stored.

In `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

You should have something like:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'YOUR_KEY'
```

Just change `:cookie:store` to `:active_record_store` like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => 'YOUR_KEY'
```